# CodeIgniter - inserting and viewing record

Tags: codeigniter

I was wondering if somebody can enlighten me. My controller function takes a form input request and saves it to database through model function. My codes are below.

I have tried few ways but looks like I am stuck; below is my controller.

```
function submit_result() 
    {   
        if($this->input->post('Name') && $this->input->post('Class') &&
            $this->input->post('Subject') && $this->input->post('grade_value')  && $this->input->post('teacher_value')) 
        {
            $this->load->model('class_model');
            $this->class_model->submit_grade($this->input->post('Name'), $this->input->post('Class'), $this->input->post('Subject'), $this->input->post('grade_value'), $this->input->post('teacher_value'), $this->input->post('comment_value'));

            redirect(base_url().'Grader/search2/');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

here is the model looks like

```
function submit_grade($name, $class, $subject, $result, $teacher, $comment)
    {   
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `kepsek_ifa`.`mon_ifa_result` 
        (`id`, `Name`, `Class`, `Subject`, `Result`, `Teacher`, `Comment`)
        VALUES 
        (NULL," . $this->db->escape($name) . "," . $this->db->escape($class) . ","
        . $this->db->escape($subject) . ", '$result' ," 
        . $this->db->escape($teacher) . "," . $this->db->escape($comment) . ")";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    }
}
```

and in my view I have this

```
     </head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1><?php echo $student_name?></h1>
    <div id="body">
        <p>
        <?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>

<?php if ( ! is_null($subject_result)): ?>
    <?php if (count($subject_result)): ?>
        <div style="padding-top: 20px">
        <table style="border: 1px solid black">
        <tr style="font-weight: bold"><td>CLASS</td><td>SUBJECT</td><td>RESULT</td><td>GRADER</td><td>COMMENT</td></tr>
        <?php foreach ($subject_result as $result): ?>
            <tr><td><?php echo $class ?></td><td><?php echo $result->Subject ?></td><td>
            <?php   $hidden = array('Name' => $student_name, 'Class' => $class, 'Subject' => $result->Subject);
                    echo form_open("Grader/submit_result", '', $hidden);
            ?>
            <?php echo form_dropdown('grade_value', $grade_code); ?>
            </td><td>
            <?php echo form_dropdown('teacher_value', $teacher_data); ?>

                        </td><td>
                        <?php echo form_input('comment_value'); ?>
                        <?php echo form_submit('submit_result', 'Submit'); ?>
                        </td><td>

            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            </td></tr>

        <?php endforeach ?>

        </table>

        <p><a href="<?php echo base_url(). "Grader/search2" ?>"> HOME </a></p> 
    </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p><em>There are no results for your query.</em></p>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endif ?>
        </p>
    </div>

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
</div>
```

I have the view perfectly set up except for the part where it will have one submit button for each row, what I want is one submit button to save all data in my view

I have tried different combination like using form_hidden on my view but still failed.

The question

How ta have only one submit page in my view that will save all the record submitted by the user?
Any help ?

Comment: Please ask a specific question, instead of just "here's my code and it's broken."

Comment: My question is on the bottom of the post, I wanted to have one submit button that will save all query result, it is working now , but each row is having their own submit button

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:
In your view file:

```
 <?php 
     echo form_open("Grader/submit_result"); 
     echo form_hidden('Name' , $student_name);
     echo form_hidden('Class' , $class);
  ?>
 <table style="border: 1px solid black">
    <tr style="font-weight: bold"><td>CLASS</td><td>SUBJECT</td><td>RESULT</td><td>GRADER</td><td>COMMENT</td></tr>
    <?php 
        form_hidden('username', 'johndoe');
        foreach ($subject_result as $result): ?>
        <tr><td><?php echo $class ?></td><td><?php echo $result->Subject ?></td><td>
        <?php   

             echo form_hidden('Subject[]',$result->Subject);
        ?>
        <?php echo form_dropdown('grade_value[]', $grade_code); ?>
        </td><td>
        <?php echo form_dropdown('teacher_value[]', $teacher_data); ?>

                    </td><td>
                    <?php echo form_input('comment_value'); ?>
                    <?php echo form_submit('submit_result', 'Submit'); ?>
                    </td><td>


        </td></tr>

    <?php endforeach ?>

    </table>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

In your controller loop through subject count.

```
   $c = count($this->input->post('Subject'));
   for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
        $subject = $this->input->post('Subject')[$i];
        $grade_value = $this->input->post('grade_value')[$i];
        $teacher_value = $this->input->post('teacher_value')[$i];

       // insert code goes here.
   }
```

Comment: Any part I am missing or if you can, can you send me the full code i need to upload on my script